# Formating iptables output and monitor in real time

Tags: awk, grep, iptables, cut

My iptables rules consist some long entries, f.e. `LOG` target, this is causing not very nice output when I try to monitor it with `watch` command.

Since I am testing on lap-top, screen is not so wide. So what I thought, is it possible to exclude the last column from display?
This is some example how my rules looks like:

```
$IT -A tcpLog -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,ACK SYN,ACK -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j LOG --log-prefix "[BAD TCP]" --log-level warning -m limit --limit 10/m
$IT -A tcpLog -p tcp --tcp-flags FIN,ACK FIN -j LOG --log-prefix "[BAD TCP]" --log-level warning -m limit --limit 10/m
$IT -A tcpLog -p tcp --tcp-flags ACK,PSH PSH -j LOG --log-prefix "[BAD TCP]" --log-level warning -m limit --limit 10/m
```

so how would I exclude the last column, which displays in this case, log prefix and related info?

Also, I monitor it like `watch -n 1 iptables -L -nv`
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to exclude the last column of an output:

```
my_command | awk '{ $NF="" } 1'
```

Personally, I would prefer to truncate the output to a specific width, with one of the following commands:

```
my_command | pr -t -W "$COLUMNS"
my_command | cut -c "-$COLUMNS"
```

Here `COLUMNS` is a variable set by `bash` to the width of your terminal when the option `checkwinsize` is on (`shopt -s checkwinsize`). You can of course use any number of your choice instead.

Comment: `my_command | pr -t -W "$COLUMNS"` doing a job for me. Thanks a lot!